# How to remove spacing between nested tables?

Tags: html, css

I know this question might have been asked for a few times now.But none of the answers are able to solve my problem. Anyway I have the following HTML

```html
<table style="height: 305px;" border="1" width="579" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 137px;">A</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">B</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">C</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">
<table style="height: 79px;" border="1" width="140" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 39px;">1</td>
<td style="width: 39px;">2</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 39px;">4</td>
<td style="width: 39px;">5</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 137px;">E</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">F</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">G</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">
<table style="height: 107px;" border="1" width="142" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">1</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">2</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">4</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">5</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">7</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">8</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">10</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">11</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">12</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 137px;">I</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">J</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">K</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to display the last column of the table only onClick but the thing is the last cell which consists the nested table spaces out no matter what I try to do.
I have already tried using `rowspan`, `border-collapse`, `margin` and none of this seem to help

Any inputs?

Comment: Please check your height of your table, check the master table height, reduce and see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your table to `table-layout: fixed` (you can understand how it is different from the default by heading to [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_tab_table-layout.asp)). Then set the nested tables to have a `width` and a `height` of `100%`. That should fix your issue.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table.tlf {
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
table td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table class="tlf" style="height: 305px;" border="1" width="579" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 137px;">A</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">B</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">C</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 39px;">1</td>
       <td style="width: 39px;">2</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 39px;">4</td>
       <td style="width: 39px;">5</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">6</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 137px;">E</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">F</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">G</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">
    <table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 40px;">1</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">2</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 40px;">4</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">5</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 40px;">7</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">8</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td style="width: 40px;">10</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">11</td>
       <td style="width: 40px;">12</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td style="width: 137px;">I</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">J</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">K</td>
   <td style="width: 138px;">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

---

If you want to remove the borders of the nested tables, you'll have to use a bit of CSS. Put the borders on the `td`s (instead of the tables) and give a class to the `td`s containing a table. Then, target the first two childs of that particular `td` to remove their left borders. I had to adjust the width of the nested tables to 101% though (if you intend on keeping pixel values for width, you could adjust it manually to 145px).

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table table {
  width: 101%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
table td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-container {
  border: 0;
}

.table-container tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="tlf" style="height: 305px;" width="579" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>A</td>
   <td>B</td>
   <td>C</td>
   <td class="table-container">
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>6</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>E</td>
   <td>F</td>
   <td>G</td>
   <td class="table-container">
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr>
       <td>1</td>
       <td>2</td>
       <td>3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>4</td>
       <td>5</td>
       <td>6</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>7</td>
       <td>8</td>
       <td>9</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
       <td>10</td>
       <td>11</td>
       <td>12</td>
      </tr>
     </tbody>
    </table>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>I</td>
   <td>J</td>
   <td>K</td>
   <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

---

Third solution, do not nest tables and achieve the same thing with `colspan` and `rowspan`.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

table table {
  width: 101%;
  height: 100%;
}
 
table td {
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.table-container {
  border: 0;
}

.table-container tr td:first-child {
  border-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="tlf" height="305" width="579" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2">A</td>
   <td rowspan="2">B</td>
   <td rowspan="2">C</td>
   <td rowspan="1" style="width: calc(145px/3);">1</td>
   <td rowspan="1" style="width: calc(145px/3);">2</td>
   <td rowspan="1" style="width: calc(145px/3);">3</td>

  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="1">4</td>
   <td rowspan="1">5</td>
   <td rowspan="1">6</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="4">E</td>
   <td rowspan="4">F</td>
   <td rowspan="4">G</td>
   <td rowspan="1">1</td>
   <td rowspan="1">2</td>
   <td rowspan="1">3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="1">4</td>
   <td rowspan="1">5</td>
   <td rowspan="1">6</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="1">7</td>
   <td rowspan="1">8</td>
   <td rowspan="1">9</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="1">10</td>
   <td rowspan="1">11</td>
   <td rowspan="1">12</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>I</td>
   <td>J</td>
   <td>K</td>
   <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: But you could still see that minute gap between borders? I want that entire table as a cell to the parent table

Comment: I'll update my answer, we need to use `border-collapse` for this but it only works on the `th`s and `td`s of the same parent table. We'll need to have only one table (and adjust the layout with colspans, rowspans, etc.) or to use a bit of CSS.

Comment: @AriiNkhun Is your problem fixed ? Was my answer the solution to your problem ? If so, mark it as accepted please.

Comment: I achieved it using `rowspan`. Thanks for the help. It not only fixed my problem but also helped me gain some knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

Here you are:
You need to remove nested tables outline borders with **border: none** property

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
          body {
        font-family: sans-serif;
      }

      table.tlf {
        table-layout: fixed;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      table table {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%; 
      }

      .no-bord {
        border: none;
      }
       
      table td {
        text-align: center;
      }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<table class="tlf" style="height: 305px;" border="1" width="579" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 137px;">A</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">B</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">C</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">
<table class = "no-bord" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 39px;">1</td>
<td style="width: 39px;">2</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 39px;">4</td>
<td style="width: 39px;">5</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">6</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 137px;">E</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">F</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">G</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">
<table class = "no-bord" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">1</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">2</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">4</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">5</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">6</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">7</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">8</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 40px;">10</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">11</td>
<td style="width: 40px;">12</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="width: 137px;">I</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">J</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">K</td>
<td style="width: 138px;">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However I did it with `rowspan`